# Java Matlab engine install

Tags: java, matlab, jar

I am trying to use Matlab engine on Java.

I am using this guide:  https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/setup-environment.html#bvcubp5

They say that the file that I  need is located in

matlabroot/extern/engines/java/jar/engine.jar

But my folder Engines just has a folder called Phyton, I am using Matlab 2016

where should I downlod this file ?
or how else can I use Matlab Engine from Java.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=49425349829228631027) from R2016b (Windows installation).

Comment: Hello, Thank for that link,
I have a few quentions:
Will it work with 2016 a? 
Will it work with abuntu ?
How did you find it?

Thanks.

Comment: @Devil-iL Thanks anyway =)

Comment: @Devil-iL I tried your file but  wen a tried to compile any of the examples of this page https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/execute-matlab-functions-from-java.html

they dont compile  because ¨ the method Feval is not applicable  for those arguments ¨ 

Do you know what should I do ?
Greetings.